# How to get navigation object outside Screen

Tags: react-navigation

I have the following code in the App.tsx:

```
export default function App() {
...
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="StackNavigation"
        drawerContent={(props) => <MainPageDrawer {...props} />}
        screenOptions={{ swipeEnabled: false }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="StackNavigation" component={StackNavigator} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
...
}
```

As you see, the `MainPageDrawer` component isn't inside the `Drawer.Screen` component. But I still need to get access to `navigation` object inside `MainPageDrawer`. When I do something lake this inside `MainPageDrawer`:

```
  const navigation = useNavigation<MainScreenNavigationProp>();
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?
```

What is the right way to get access to the `navigation` object outside `Screen` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I figured out that `useNavigation` won't work anyway if it is outside `Screen`, BUT this:

```
(props) => <MainPageDrawer {...props} />
```

still pass `navigation` through props, so you can easily access it without `useNavigation`. I simply restructured `navigation`:

```
function MainPageDrawer({ navigation }) {
...
}
```

And it works

Comment: If you want to do the same in the root element you need to use ref on the navigation container.